# Is there a way to pull a list of fields needing read-only (for lookups) and edit (for create/update) access in order to run a specific flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions, documentation, access

As we transition from profiles to permission sets, I'm being asked to provide a listing of all fields needed in order to run a few certain flows to ensure we have all the permissions we need, and not any we don't need.  These are field service mobile flows that can only run in user context, so wen't can't just update the context of the flow.